# Do I need HTML files in my site for Google Bot?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

My question is, if I'm using a `.htaccess` file like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^members/([^/\.]+)/?$ /forum/view_member.php?member=$1
```

then do I need a file say `members/kernel_kev.html` or `members/kernel_kev/index.html` that would pretty much be blank, but needs to be there for google to see it and cache it so that each thread, member profile etc will be on google search results?

I'm a little confused on how this would work without any html files and just a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Can I remind folks that questions about rewriting **are** valid on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has no way of differentiating between a file on the disk and a URL you generate programmatically. It's simply requesting a URL, which interprets using mod_rewrite to figure out how to handle, and the result is returned.

There are specific URLs that google may look for directly (like 'robots.txt', for instance), but most of the pages it will be looking for would be through links (wither originally from your main page or from some other site.

Answer (score 1):

A Google Bot would see what anyone else sees in the browser, so you shouldn't have to do anything special to accommodate them.

Comment: So does it start at my forum homepage and then look at the links, then follow each link from there on?

Comment: Yes. Any links that are visible to the browser it would follow.